# How to auto rotate and sync nav buttons using jquery tools slideshow plugin for tabs?

Tags: slideshow, jquery-tools, flowplayer, jquery-tabs

Using jQuery Tools from flowplayer.org I'm not understanding how to make my Slides auto rotate and sync of navigation dots per slide??

I'm using Slideshow Plugin for Tabs in order to show lots info. Works great manually clicking through slides but would like to make them rotate automatically.

Tried doing the chaining plugins bit but not seeming to work out so hot.

```
    <!-- START SLIDE GROUP CONTAINER -->
    <div class="slide_group" id="slide_group_queue_service">

      <!-- container for the slides -->
      <div class="images" id="chained">

        <!-- first slide -->
        <div>info in here</div>

        <!-- second slide -->
        <div>info in here</div>

        <!-- third slide -->
        <div>info in here</div>

      </div>

      <!-- the tabs -->
      <div class="slidetabs">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END SLIDE GROUP CONTAINER -->


    <!-- SLIDE TABS FOR BUSINESSES PAGE -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

    // start from the beginning after the last tab
    rotate: true

    // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
    }).slideshow();
    });

    $("#chained").scrollable({circular: true, mousewheel:true}).navigator().autoscroll({
interval: 3000
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. I really just used a slightly different formatted version located at:
http://www.jquerytools.org/

Using Sliding Tabs just wasn't the best option. Same exact HTML structure, but the JS to trigger it and it's CSS was a bit more specific.